# Error While Adding library for CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-cardview

When i am adding the library for CardView ("compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'") in my build.gradle ( Module : app ) file it is showing me error

Please help me in this !!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.trysafe.trysafecfs"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

it is showing me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value 
value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] 
AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
    is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] 
AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at 
AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

Comment: Make sure your CardView library has the same like the other support libraries. So `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
```

Because **ALL support libs shoud be the same version**.

Comment: `26.+` is not recommended you should use exact version code .

Answer (score 0):

Use exact same version of dependency instead of `26.+`

**`compile`** is deprecated

Also Use **`implementation`** instead of **`compile`**

Try this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Than **`clean - Re-Build - Run`** your project